# Add additional tab after reviews

Tags: magento2, product, layout, tabs, design

I am trying to have a few more additional tabs added after the Reviews tab, though my tab keeps appearing as the first tab

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="postage.tab" as="postage" template="product/view/postage.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Postage</argument>
             </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Paul, You can use `after` and `before` tag to adjust position of tab

Answer (score 2):

Check it, if it solves your problem

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block  class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="postage.tab1" as="postage1" 
            template="[Vendor]_[Module]::postage1.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Postage1</argument>
             </arguments>
          </block>
          <block  class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="postage.tab2" as="postage2" 
            template="[Vendor]_[Module]::postage2.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Postage2</argument>
             </arguments>
          </block>
          <block  class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="postage.tab3" as="postage3" 
            template="[Vendor]_[Module]::postage3.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Postage3</argument>
             </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Comment: this still seems to make it the first tab

Comment: tabs are displayed after review tab

Comment: see above with the image

Comment: which theme and magento version you are using

Comment: Magento 2.3.1 and luma

Comment: you can set priority or sort on tabs to change their position

`<argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">50</argument>`

Comment: this was close, i use what you provided and did some further digging. on magento 2.3.1 priority can be changed to sort_order

Comment: ok if it work, kindly let me know and upvote the answer